# NSuserdefaults UISwitch

Tags: label, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have some problems on save the position of switch,any help?

```
- (IBAction)SWitchActionAño:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (switchAño.on) {
     [standardDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchState"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm"];
    diadelasemanalabel.text=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
} else {
    [standardDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchState"];
    Año.text=@"";
}

}
```

but i have the problem here! I dont know what is the property!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//the error here:property switchAño not found on object....
if ([standardDefaults objectForKey:@"SwitchState"])
    self.switchAño.on =[standardDefaults boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([standardDefaults boolForKey:@"SwitchState"] == YES) {
    self.switchAño.on = YES;
}
else {
    self.switchAño.on = NO
}
```